# htaccess redirect if URI matches and doesn't have anything after it

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a bit of an issue with a 301 redirect to fix some client site requirements.

Here's the scenario:

If I go to `website.com/case-studies` I would like it to redirect to `website.com/case-studies/any/any/any`, however, if we have something like `website.com/case-studies/technology/any/any` it shouldn't redirect.

I have tried `Redirect 301 /case-studies /case-studies/any/any/any` but this basically put me in a loop of `/any` * 30 appearing in the address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to a regex based directive and use anchors. So use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/case-studies/?$ /case-studies/any/any/any
```

Regex `^/case-studies/?$` will match `/case-studies` or `/case-studies/` but it won't match anything beyond that.

Make sure to clear your browser cache when testing this change.

Comment: Running this in incognito works perfectly. Is there anything I can do to ensure the user doesn't have the same issue I did with the repeating `/any` in the address bar?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. What is the issue with multiple `/any`?

Comment: If I go to my address (I'm using Expression Engine), and do something like `website.com/case-studies/any/any/any/P9` which is a pagination link it literally does this `website.com/case-studies/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/any/P9` but in incognito it doesn't (as per your comment)

Comment: Right that is because you used `301` in your rules and browser has caches bad redirection. Once you completely clear browser cache then it will be fine.

Comment: So it's likely that website users are going to be presented with this bug for a while? Is there no way to enforce a refresh or anything?

Comment: For users that already have bad cache (client side),I don't think we can do server side. That's why it is not recommended to use `301` in testing redirect rules.